# How to Show Thumbnails in Video Sequence Editor strips?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is there a way to show thumbnails in Video Sequence Editor strips?
If not, is this a feature we can request for a future version of blender?
Here is a thread that discusses this idea, but it doesn't look like it made it into blender 2.8+
https://devtalk.blender.org/t/vse-strip-previews/5854

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's now implemented in Blender 3. Open the *Sequencer Overlays* and enable *Thumbnails*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No one is working on it, so it'll only be implemented if someone picks it up and do the work: https://developer.blender.org/D5908

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you don't see the thumbnails, make sure to zoom in the video sequencer (took me a while to figure that out).